# attach an application into another in C#

Tags: c#

how i can attach any other application to my application? ،
my goal is that i want load and run a .exe application by my application starting.
any one can help me ?

Answer (score 7):

So you want to start a new [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) from your application?

```
// Start Internet Explorer. Defaults to the home page.
Process.Start("IExplore.exe");
```

Answer (score 4):

You might mean `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe")` for instance, but without a bit more info, it's hard to tell whether you are after a more specific answer.